# Run Rails 2.2.2 application with Phusion Passenger 5.0.30

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I have my server running rails 4.2 applications with phusion passenger 5.0.30. But I need to set up one of our old websites on this server which is running on Rails 2.2.2 and ruby ruby-1.8.7-p352. I know I can not run rails 2.2.x applications with phusion passenger 5.x. So is there a way I can install some other passenger version particularly for this website? Or shall I go with ProxyPass. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you use a VM (e.g. vagrant) or docker container? Or, just spin up another server?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to run application by ProxyPass instead of having all these installations?

Comment: Sure, but I don't know if that will solve the compatibility issue. I'm just throwing alternate ideas out there, in particular on the question of "installing another passenger version", in case you hit a brick wall. It's been over 5 years since I attempted to run a ruby 1.8 application.

Comment: It's quite possible that you'll hit some *other* issues when trying to install such an old application on a modern machine, such as using OpenSSL or compiling native C extensions. Which is why it *may* be worth considering running a second server, or a VM, or a (docker?) container.